# What data type does a fabric-composer transaction return?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am confused as to what data type my fabric ledger transactions need to return.

The sample-network makes believe a Promise needs to be returned, but it isn't clear to me if the a Promise is the expected return value and/or if the returned Promise needs to return any particular type (e.g. String or a boolean).

```
function onSampleTransaction(sampleTransaction) {
    sampleTransaction.asset.value = sampleTransaction.newValue;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset')
      .then(function (assetRegistry) {
          return assetRegistry.update(sampleTransaction.asset);
      });
}
```

What data type does a fabric-composer transaction return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the transaction to be executed, you must return *a* Promise, but the type returned by the Promise does not matter.

Comment: If the Promise's return type does not matter, is there any way to signal a the transaction's result as a success or failure?

Comment: Other than throwing an error if parameters aren't correct, no. If you are using hyperledger fabric 1.0 you will be given an error back, however in 0.6, you will only see a transaction timeout error. You will see an error in the chaincode using both

Answer (score 0):

Return type is always a **Promise**, developer an resolve the type based on his knowledge or the type it is returning. For example, **Exists** function returns a Promise which can be resolved as a Boolean, having value either true or false.